# C# (.Net5.0) Project uses System.Media.SystemSounds, but VS2019 says I now need to use System.Windows.Extensions.SystemSounds (.Net7.0)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

As the headline says, I have an existing .Net5.0 C# project that uses the `System.Media.SystemSounds` class, but VS2019 has suddenly started throwing the error:

> Error CS1069: The type name 'SystemSounds' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Media'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Windows.Extensions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

I've found this new module (`System.Windows.Extensions`) in Nuget, and applied it to my project, but it doesn't appear, and I'm still getting the error.

I assume that this is because the project itself is still targeted to .Net5.0 but the dependencies for `System.Windows.Extensions` say it needs the .Net7.0 class `System.Drawing.Common` The problem being that I can't find how to add even .Net6.0 support to Visual Studio 2019, let alone 7.0, so I don't know how to get my project to compile anymore?

Can someone point me towards a solution for either forcing VS2019 to use the (apparently deprecated) `System.Media.SystemSounds` class, or tell me how to enable/activate/apply .Net7.0 and activate the new `System.Windows.Extensions` features?

Comment: You have download the wrong version, make sure it's the version for .net 5, when you install.

Comment: @PoulBak I can't FIND any other version... and ```System.Media``` was the proper mechanism for accessing the ```SystemSounds``` class in .Net5.0 (until recently apparently!) If you know where to find the ```System.Windows.Extensions``` add-on for .Net5.0, please share!

Comment: When you INSTALL the version from Nuget you can select a version from the dropdown box (don't select the latest version).

Comment: Heh, okay, I found that, and pulled the version 5.0 implementation and suddenly ```System.Media.SystemSounds``` works again! The only thing I'm concerned about now is that the system says this module is out of date and needs updating. It's showing the current (v7.0) one as the requisite replacement, and I'm halfway anticipating that a stealth update may have been what caused this problem originally, and could well occur again at any time...

Comment: @NetXpert May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any others questions.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT - inasmuch as it seems like you basically took the solution / assistance comments that were provided above by Poul Bak on the 3rd and fleshed it out as a formal solution on the 4th, yes I've seen it; I'm just reticent to somewhat unfairly give credit for the solution that I actually followed to someone other than the person who actually provided it... Unfortunately, being as (s)he didn't post it as a solution, all I could do to show my gratitude / appreciation for their help was upvote their comments. ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

First from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.systemsounds?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) we can see that the System.Media.Systemsounds class is in System.Windows.Extensions.dll.

When you install System.Windows.Extensions from nuget you can choose the version on the left.
[image]

[This page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Extensions/6.0.0) shows 'System.Windows.Extensions 6.0.0' is compatible with .net 6.0, you can update to VS2022 to use .net 6.0.